# WPF: Is there a Limit to Storyboard Names

Tags: wpf, xaml

Recently i have implemented some Storyboards that animate some Properties of an Element and it had some weird behavior. The trigger simply didnt use one of my Storyboards, but called the wrong one.

My Storyboards (just 2 of them for showcase) have names that are quite similar to eachother, like these ones:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SomePrettyLongStoryboardNameAB" />
<Storyboard x:Key="SomePrettyLongStoryboardNameAC" />
```

The call of these Storyboard looks like this:

```
<BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SomePrettyLongStoryboardNameAB}" />
<BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SomePrettyLongStoryboardNameAC}" />
```

When i ran my program, one of the Storyboards was never called, because the Trigger used the other one. I had the idea that he might use a predefined length of Storyboard Names and then cut them, because after changing the Names from "SomePrettyLongStoryboardName**AB**" to "**AB**SomePrettyLongStoryboardName" and "SomePrettyLongStoryboardName**AC**" to  "**AC**SomePrettyLongStoryboardName" he started doing everything right.

Is my assumption right about the Storyboard Name Length, or do you have another possible solution i might try? I hope I could provide you with the information you need :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this is not the limitation of `StoryBoard`, but the `x:Key` itself

Comment: I've read the Documentation about the x:Key, but couldn't find any topic about Limitations of Length. Still seems a bit weird.

Comment: I'm doing the same, reading the docs. Couldn't find anything related to length limitation in `x.Key` or `StoryBoard`

Comment: The length of the keys of the Storyboards are most likely *not* your issue. So your assumption is wrong.

Comment: It would be really bad, if that was my issue. But thats the only thing I changed. I guess this will stay an unsolved Mistery.

Comment: At least until you provide a repo of your issue.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I know that the informations provided are limited. I can't share more code, because it's source code from work. Designing a Repo or something else would simply overextend the worthness of this issue i think. But thanks for your answers :)